# How to get sum of value for specific field

Tags: mysql

```
 -------------------------------------------------
SELECT trtm, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'TM' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Transmission,
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'TR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Transfer,
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'DL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Deletion
(SELECT 
  (SUM( tshares ) AS total WHERE trtm =  'TM'),
  (SUM( tshares ) AS total1 WHERE trtm =  'TR'))
FROM transfer_file
where t_date between '10/1/1992' and '10/2/1992'
 -----------------------------------------------
```

How to get the sum of values for specific fields,i am getting the count of value but not getting the sum of value,what to do? help me if any body knows

Answer (score 2):

You should use *conditional aggregation* inside the `SUM` too:

```sql
SELECT trtm, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'TM' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Transmission,
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'TR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Transfer,
COUNT(CASE WHEN trtm= 'DL' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Deletion
SUM(CASE WHEN trtm = 'TM' THEN tshares END) AS Total_Transmission,
SUM(CASE WHEN trtm = 'TR' THEN tshares END) AS Total_Transfer
FROM transfer_file
WHERE t_date between '10/1/1992' and '10/2/1992'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Giorgos Betsos, It was working perfectly

Comment: @YogasuganyaSukumar Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.